# Можно ли заменить реальное положение устройства?

Tags: android, android-sdk, геолокация

Можно ли сделать так чтобы Android получил ложные данные о местоположении либо вообще не получил никаких данных? И чтобы это было максимально чисто. Чтобы Third-party приложения, которые установлены на телефоне не могли даже подозревать об этом?

Comment: [fakegps](https://github.com/mcastillof/FakeTraveler) оно?

Comment: @DiD  при  подмене данных местоположений с помощью таких приложений   third - party приложения могут легко обнаружить что данные подменены .мне нужно надежный метод .

Comment: Способ надежнее некуда, у меня с fakegps дрон летает над Внуково.

Comment: @DiD когда с помощью приложений меняем данные Gps  но Cell ID нашей базовой станции показывает абсолютно другой регион (регион нашего реального местоположения ) разве  сторонние приложение  не  могут от этого  понять что полученные данные Gps ложные ? Мы знаем что в основном для позиционировании используются гибридные технологии а не конкретная технология . В таком случае если хотим передавать ложные геолокационные данные достаточно ли менять только Gps данные или нужно менять все данные которые передаются (wi fi  , GSM в тд. )?

Comment: Ну так то, когда надо скрыть местоположение, следует использовать аппарат без симкарт. А летать по зонам NFZ конечно мега-опасно. Если приложение глюканет хоть на секунду, сработает защита, двигатели дрона выключатся и дрон за 2-5 тыс. вечно-зелёных у.е. совершит самую жёсткую посадку, деформируясь в лепёшку.

Comment: @DiD в данном случае нужно  скрыть местоположение смартфона  а снимание Sim карты вопрос не решает. По IMEi все равно устройство получает Cell ID . И еще кроме GSM  можно позиционировать также по WI fi  сетям ․разве  это не показывает что подмена Gps данных с помощью приложений не надежна ?